# Looking to create a webservice for client authentication and need some advice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services

I am developing an android application to accommodate some desktop software that I created. I would like for the user of the mobile app to have to verify their identity through authentication. Basically the web service will have to act as a central hub to both authenticate and hold information that the android app will need. The way I think it should work is to

-Set up a central web service

-Allow user to create account from desktop client using email/password

-The desktop client will send the information to the webservice that the android app will need.

-when android app is authenticated it will then retrieve the data it needs that was posted from the client.

So basically the service will need to be able to send and receive data.

I will only be using .net (either C# or vb.net ) for the service, so this leads me to a couple of questions:

Should I be using WCF for this? If so should I create a WCF Service library or WCF Service application?

Should I be using the Sign Sign on service approach?

The web service doesn't need to be fancy it just needs to get the job done. Is their any boilerplate project templates or projects out their I could use to help build a foundation?

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered SudzC.com which generates classes and methods for Objective-C from the wsdl data of a .net web service, and I'm fairly sure it also does Android.

I have a huge catalog of fairly 'old' web services which pre-date WCF and they are currently working perfectly.

I should point out though that the SudzC service only shows you what it can do for you for free - to get the code you have to pay ~£20 for a one year pass.

Answer (score 0):

We had something similar where I worked. We had to put together an Android app for the company. If you are on .net 4.0 or newer, you can take advantage of the[WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api). It can return json or xml. So, that means any platform can utilize it (desktiop, android, etc...). I found it extremely easy to use, with very little overhead.